# stretch image text created by GD

Tags: php, image-manipulation, gd

I am trying to use some PHP GD functions to stretch some text in an image.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Stretch how? Would `imagecopyresized()` help?

Comment: Well I have a an image that has text displayed using imagettftext() and I'd like to distort the text so it appears to be vertically stretched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the text on an image, use `imagecopyresized` to copy it to a taller image, and by resizing the whole image you've resized the text. Now you can copy it to the final image.

Comment: Any idea how I'd change the following class to use your above answer? http://pastie.org/1373127